# How to restore values of default VPC Security group within a given availability zone?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I am operating in US-West Availability Zone.
I was trying to solve the problem for ELB and I courageously or stupidly changed the Source IP of my default VPC security group to fix it. It did not fix the original issue but now I am in to another issue.

Now I am trying to restore the default VPC security Group setting in my Amazon Web Service account.

As per my knowledge the default VPC is very restrictive.
I don't quite remember what was the value for inbound source IPs. 
The issue is that I have changed the Inbound rule's Source IP (from its original value which I do not remember) to Anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) in the default VPC Security group on AWS Console.

So how do I bring back the original default VPC security rule inbound IP setting that is applicable to my availability zone?

What is the implication of this? As a precaution I am not using default VPC Security Group on any of the EC2 instance or ELB.

Comment: By the way, since you can not delete the default security group...AWS won't allow it...so for the time being I am setting the inbound rule source IP to my own private IP...

Comment: Why can't you create a new SG to suit your needs and just do not use the default SG.

Comment: Yes. That is what I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Default VPC security group can not be deleted
- You can make changes though
- The default VPC security group simply points to its own Group-ID.

  So you know how to restore the default VPC rule if you mess up with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can search the informations inside AWS Forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=58

Many people open tickets similar to your problem.

Comment: Those tickets are apparently resolved by the customer support person editing the rule, so they aren't very helpful for a person trying to fix the issue themselves.